# XSUB not receiving in ZeroMQ XSUB/PUB setup

Tags: python, zeromq, pyzmq

I would like to use XSUB/XPUB to enable multiple ZMQ publishers and subscribers. Everything works when I use `zmq.proxy(xpub_socket, xsub_socket)`, but I need something custom because I need to write code between XSUB and XPUB that examines the messages.

Here's where I'm at:

```py
import time
import zmq

context = zmq.Context()

address = '127.0.0.1'
pub_port = '3000'
sub_port = '3001'

# XSUB socket
xsub_socket = context.socket(zmq.XSUB)
xsub_socket.bind(f'tcp://{address}:{pub_port}')

# XPUB socket
xpub_socket = context.socket(zmq.XPUB)
xpub_socket.bind(f'tcp://{address}:{sub_port}')

time.sleep(1)

# PUB socket
pub_socket = context.socket(zmq.PUB)
pub_socket.connect(f'tcp://{address}:{pub_port}')

# SUB socket
sub_socket = context.socket(zmq.SUB)
sub_socket.subscribe('')
sub_socket.connect(f'tcp://{address}:{sub_port}')

time.sleep(1)

pub_socket.send_string('test')

time.sleep(1)

print(poller.poll(0))
```

The values sent from the PUB socket do not reach the XSUB socket.

I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24593274/zeromq-xsub-does-not-receive) that the first byte needs to be 1. Both of these also don't work:

```py
pub_socket.send(b'\x01')
pub_socket.send_multipart([b'\x01', 'test'.encode('utf-8')])
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: It would help if you could edit your code to produce a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It's much easier for us to help you if we can run your code and reproduce the problem you're describing.

Comment: Given your current code, I don't see where you're passing messages between the XPUB and XSUB sockets. If you're not using a `zmq.Proxy()`, you need to perform this operation yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `PUB` socket won't send any messages to an `XSUB` socket unless it has received a subscription request, which you get by calling `subscribe` on a `SUB` socket.

The only way those subscription messages get passed through is if you set up your `XSUB/XPUB` proxy.

Here's a simple proxy that connects an `XPUB` and `XSUB` socket, printing out messages it receives in either direction:

```
import zmq

ctx = zmq.Context()

xpub_sock = ctx.socket(zmq.XPUB)
xpub_sock.bind("tcp://127.0.0.1:3000")

xsub_sock = ctx.socket(zmq.XSUB)
xsub_sock.bind("tcp://127.0.0.1:3001")

poller = zmq.Poller()
poller.register(xpub_sock, zmq.POLLIN)
poller.register(xsub_sock, zmq.POLLIN)

while True:
    socks = dict(poller.poll())
    if xpub_sock in socks and socks[xpub_sock] == zmq.POLLIN:
        msg = xpub_sock.recv_multipart()
        print("(sub)", msg)
        xsub_sock.send_multipart(msg)
    elif xsub_sock in socks and socks[xsub_sock] == zmq.POLLIN:
        msg = xsub_sock.recv_multipart()
        print("(pub)", msg)
        xpub_sock.send_multipart(msg)
```

If I connect to this with an `PUB` socket, like this...

```
import zmq
import time

ctx = zmq.Context()
pub_sock = ctx.socket(zmq.PUB)
pub_sock.connect("tcp://localhost:3001")

while True:
    pub_sock.send_string("test")
    time.sleep(1)
```

...I won't see any messages arriving at the `XSUB` socket, because
there are no active subscriptions. However, if I connect a `SUB`
socket to the `XPUB` socket and set a subscription...

```
import zmq

ctx = zmq.Context()
sub_sock = ctx.socket(zmq.SUB)
sub_sock.connect("tcp://localhost:3000")
sub_sock.subscribe("")

while True:
    msg = sub_sock.recv()
    print(msg)
```

...then I will start to see messages passing from the `PUB` socket to
the `XSUB` socket, and then from the `XPUB` socket to the `SUB`
socket.

Comment: Awesome explanation! I was so caught up in the abstract idea that PUB/SUB is a form of one-way communication that I didn't realize that the SUB socket needs to send its subscription before it can begin.

Comment: Amazing explanation. Thank you.